# Using color variables in WRITE statement

Tags: list, colors, abap

How can I use color value variable? For example, this works for me:

```
write:/10  'test' COLOR COL_HEADING.
```

I thoght that colours are integers so I tried:

```
data:
gv_mycolor type I.
gv_mycolor = 5.
write:/10  'test' COLOR gv_mycolor.
```

the second code gives me an error: 
"Color gv_mycolor is not expected; only 1 to 7 or the relevant color IDs are allowed. Statement

```
FORMAT COLOR = gv_mycolor.
```

works for me, I have problem just with write statement.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - are you really still using old lists for new programs instead of newer technologies?

Comment: Yes, I am just beginner and just learning ABAP. What are the new technologies?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
DATA colour TYPE i VALUE 2.

WRITE:/10  'test' COLOR = colour .
```

You MUST use an equal sign, and that's all there is to it... ABAP and it's funny statements :P

Comment: I'm really tempted to rate this -1 instead of +1, just because it helps people create more unmaintainable list code :-)

Comment: lol, please spare me :P I promiss I try to use the new stuff as much as I can. I come from the Java world, the `WRITE` statement still horrifies me.

Comment: You have my reluctant vote :), given that you have answered the actual question. Anyhow having spend the last two weeks on HRFORMS, it has taken the top spot for things that have to die a slow and horrible death. So I will give ABAP lists a reprieve for now :)

Comment: Dunno about HRForms, but SAPScript is the worst of what i've seen so far :P

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  First part of the answer is hidden as it is incorrect - see Vlad's comment & answer

> **Short answer to your question:**  The syntax does not allow you to do this as per the compiler message.
>  
>  The best you can do is to combine the FORMAT and WRITE statements in a
>  macro, but this is very old-school, and will probably not teach you
>  too much that is relevant.

Have a look at package SLIS where there are many examples (`BCALV_GRID*`) of how to implement ALV lists and grids.  These are used much more frequently, even in Web Dynpro.  The `CL_SALV*` classes also provides a nice simplified (and supported) interface to implement ALV grids.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575989/25687) for a full example).

Comment: Why not go all the way to the documented and supported SALV classes? ;-)

Comment: Hmm I was attempting and failed to reference SALV, a single S makes a world of difference.

Comment: Actually the syntax does allow it :) it's just that an '=' sign must be added, as in `...COLOR = inv_value.`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a basic pallet of colors using the COLOR attribute.

Here is the sample code:

```
 WRITE: '|......TESTMODE......|' COLOR = 1, /.
 WRITE: '|......TESTMODE......|' COLOR = 2, /.
 WRITE: '|......TESTMODE......|' COLOR = 3, /.
 WRITE: '|......TESTMODE......|' COLOR = 4, /.
 WRITE: '|......TESTMODE......|' COLOR = 5, /.
 WRITE: '|......TESTMODE......|' COLOR = 6, /.
 WRITE: '|......TESTMODE......|' COLOR = 7, /.
```

And the output:

[image: Output code WRITE color]