# Read tab Delimited Text File From Local Machine

Tags: text-files, abap

This is my first try at ABAP. I'm interning in the IT dept of a company and the project I'm on right now requires me to write a relatively simple program, as I've never written anything substantial in ABAP. I'm at a loss as to where to start.

As a starting point, I'm just trying to read in and then display the values of a tab delimited text file. Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Do you have to code this for yourself or are you also interested in pointers to generic tools that already implement this?

Comment: the file you're loading, are you loading it from your desktop or the application servers?

Answer (score 1):

Use method `cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_upload` to upload the file.  `cl_gui_frontent_services` also has some other handy methods like `FILE_OPEN_DIALOG` that you can use as an F4-fieldhelp to select the file that you would like to upload.

You should be able to use the "where-used" function to see how these methods are implemented.

Use the various `CL_SALV*` classes to display the uploaded file. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575989/25687) for a more detailed overview of the `CL_SALV*` Classes).

Have a look at the demo programs in package SLIS for more options on displaying lists.  (`SALV_DEMO_TABLE_COLUMNS_GROUP` looks like a good SALV example)